# Popup LOV item settings

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to disable Popup LOV item search bar and load by default all rows from SQL Query? Item has an JavaScript Initialization Code block, but I can find documentation how use it (for example like Rich Text Editor or Charts). For now I disabled Popup LOV search bar using CSS, but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Popup LOV on my 18.2 returns all rows by default ... No JavaScript, no CSS, nothing.

Comment: Remove the search bar in the popup lov? Why not just use a select list?

Comment: @Littlefoot, didn't known about that, but why it displays "Load More Rows" button?

Comment: @Scott, because I want to display a few columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable the search bar declaratively.
The CSS way is indeed your best bet.

Concerning the JavaScript Initialization Code attribute, the first thing I always do before putting anything in there is the following:

```js
function(options){
    console.log(options);
    return options;
}
```

then checking the console. Usually you will see all of the declarative values and defaults for any other fancy things.

Your second option would be to check the actual source code, which usually includes some JSDoc. In the case of the Popup LOV, you want to look at [this file](https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/20.2.0.00.20/libraries/apex/widget.popupLov.js). Of course the easiest way to get to these things is to put your app in debug mode, and navigate through the files in the Sources Panel.